# Dimensional Analysis - Finding dimension of $α$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

How can the dimension of $α$ be calculated?

$$y = Ae^{αt}$$

$t$ = Time
$y$ = Displacement

*Now I don't know what does $A$ and $e$ mean and the I am stuck up* here.

y = Ae<sup>αt</sup>
[L] = [A][e]<sup>[α][T]</sup>

*What to do next any ideas!*

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $$y=Ae^{\alpha t}$$
$e$ represent [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function). It' number whose value is around $2.7$. The power of exponential must be unitless. So that
$$[\alpha ][t]=M^0L^0T^0$$
From where you can determine the unit of $\alpha$. To determine the unit of $A$, Note that the unit of both sides must be the same. $e^\cdots$
is unit less so the unit of $A$ must be equal to that of $y$.

---

More on [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)